# Unable to set activity indicator using SDWebImage

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I'm unable to set an activity indicator in two images that use the SDWebImage for downloading pictures asynchronously. Here's my code:

```
 if let imgId = experimentFetched[0].backgroundImageId {
            print("Inside if")
            backgroundImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            backgroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
            backgroundImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:    Constants.apiBaseUrl + "Images/" + imgId), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "stock"))
            foregroundImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            backgroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
            foregroundImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: Constants.apiBaseUrl + "Images/" + imgId), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "stock"))
        }
```

I know that the if-loop is running(the print statement inside it runs..)

Comment: you can use this plugin for an easy way: https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 & SDWebImage 4.0.0**

This will do the trick, try this code

```
        // if you don't use placeholder use this
        let urlString = URL(string: url)
        yourImageView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        yourImageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: urlString) { (loadedImage, error, cacheType, url) in
            yourImageView.sd_removeActivityIndicator()
            if error != nil {
                print("Error code: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                yourImageView.image = loadedImage
            }
        }

        // if you use image placeholder use this instead
        let urlString = URL(string: url)
        yourImageView.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        yourImageView.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        yourImageView.sd_setImage(with: urlString, placeholderImage: UIImage("Your placeholeder image name")) { (loadedImage, error, cacheType, url) in
            yourImageView.sd_removeActivityIndicator()
            if error != nil {
                print("Error code: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                yourImageView.image = loadedImage
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it might be like this

```
if let imgId = experimentFetched[0].backgroundImageId {
        print("Inside if")
        backgroundImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        backgroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        backgroundImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:    Constants.apiBaseUrl + "Images/" + imgId), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "stock"))
        foregroundImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
        foregroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
        foregroundImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: Constants.apiBaseUrl + "Images/" + imgId), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "stock"))
    }
```

You duplicated

```
backgroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
```

instead of using

```
foregroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
```

for the second imageview

Answer (score 0):

**Try using this:**

```
    if let imgId = experimentFetched[0].backgroundImageId {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("Inside if")
            backgroundImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            backgroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
            backgroundImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:    Constants.apiBaseUrl + "Images/" + imgId), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "stock"))
            foregroundImage.sd_setIndicatorStyle(.gray)
            foregroundImage.sd_setShowActivityIndicatorView(true)
            foregroundImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: Constants.apiBaseUrl + "Images/" + imgId), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "stock"))
    }
}
```